# Proof about Lebesgue measure

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I have been working on Lebesgue measure, I've found a problem which I don't see clearly how to prove it. First, let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with measure $0$, then its closure also has measure $0$. Also with the reciprocal.

And finally, if $A$ (set) has measure $0$, then its interior is empty.

Comment: what is the reciprocal?

Comment: First, let E be a subset of R^2 with measure 0, then its closure also has measure 0. The reciprocal: If the closure of E (subset of R^2) has measure 0, then E has measure 0.

Comment: what about $E=\mathbb{Q}^2$? (it's countable hence measure $0$ but its closure is $\mathbb{R}^2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the first question is true, as suggested in the comments you can take $E = \mathbb{Q}^2$, which is a null set, but since cl($\mathbb{Q}^2$) = $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have a counterexample.

To prove that if $A$ has $0$ measure then its interior is empty suppose the contrary. By definition of interior exists an open set $U \subseteq A$ and you can easily take an open rectangle $B$ so that $\lambda(B) > 0$, but then $\lambda (E) \geq \lambda (B) > 0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you, first question can be answered with that counterexample, but what about the reciprocal? If the closure of E (a subset of R^2) has measure 0, then E has measure 0?

Comment: @RobbyS. Are you assuming $E$ to be measurable ? If so just look at the contrapositive

Comment: @jacopoburrelli Im assuming that if closure of E has 0 measure, then I have to prove E is not measurable (or give another counterexample for this statement)

Comment: @RobbyS. "Im assuming that if closure of E has 0 measure, then I have to prove E is not measurable" I don't get this sentence, since written in this way doesn't seem true to me, think to Cantor set. Please rephrase the question, what do you want to prove ?

Comment: Excuse me if you don't understand me, sorry. I just want to prove this: " If closure of E (subset of R^2) has 0 measure, then E has 0 measure ".Before, you gave me a counterexample of " If E (subset of R^2) has 0 measure, then its closure has 0 measure "

Comment: If you let $E$ to be measurable, look at the contrapositive, it gives by hp that $\lambda(E) > 0$ then $\lambda(\overline{E}) \geq \lambda (E) > 0 $, hence the thesis you're looking for (note we already know that $\overline{E}$ is measurable)

Comment: *If closure of E (subset of R^2) has 0 measure, then E has 0 measure* --- **Lemma 1:** If $H \subseteq {\mathbb R}^2$ has measure zero and $G \subseteq H,$ then $G$ has measure zero. **Lemma 2:** Let $E \subset {\mathbb R}^.$ Then $E \subset \overline{E}.$ **Theorem:** If $\overline{E}$ has measure zero, then $E$ has measure zero.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro It's exactly what I wrote that's why I asked for misurability of $E$

Comment: *It's exactly what I wrote that's why I asked for* --- I suspect the OP is very new with these concepts and became confused when you began taking about the interior of a set when the question involved the closure of a set.